# Importing MySQL Database to Parse Android

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I am developing an android application that requires an online database. I'm facing issues in connecting my application to the online server, so I decided to use Parse. It seems interesting, efficient and much easier. But I have already developed my database and I wonder if there is a way to import it to Parse Cloud. And if there isn't, how can I set my own database on Parse and create, edit and read from tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android app does not (direct) connect external DB
so many app connect 3rd part API page

app <-> 3rd part api page (Json, xml, etc...) <-> Database

Comment: Ok, I converted my SQL tables to JSON using PHP and now I'll follow the parse tutorials to import this data. Thanks :)

Comment: for android, using jackson or gson libary has easily parse JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **rest** or **soap** webservices. It would be easier this way.